# 500 (Internal Server Error) Yii2 Dependent Dropdown

Tags: php, yii2

Hello this is my first time trying to do a dropdown from a scratch in yii2, I was reading some tutorials in their wiki and followed the instructions.

My problem is that the dependent dropdown does not work, when I choose a category nothing happens in sub category, the subcategory just list down all the subcategory names.

In my SubCatController:

```
 public function actionLists($id)
{
    $countSubCat = SubCat::find()
                ->where(['category_id' => $id])
                ->count();

    $SubCat = SubCat::find()
                ->where(['category_id' => $id])
                ->count();

    if ($countSubCat > 0) {
        foreach($SubCat as $id) {
            echo "<option value'".$id->id."'>".$id->sub_category."</option>";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "<option>-</option>";
    }
}
```

And in my form:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'category_id')->dropDownlist(
                                            ArrayHelper::map(Category::find()->all(), 'id', 'category_name'),
                                            [
                                                'prompt' => 'Select Category',
                                                'onchange' => '
                                                    $.post( "index.php?r=sub-cat/lists&id='.'"+$(this).val(), function( data ) {
                                                        $( "select#models-contact" ).html( data );
                                                    });'

                                            ]
); ?>

 <?= $form->field($model, 'sub_cat_id')->dropDownlist(
                                            ArrayHelper::map(SubCat::find()->all(), 'id', 'sub_category'),
                                            [
                                                'prompt' => 'Select Sub Category',

                                            ]
); ?>
```

I'm stuck with this one I can't really figure it out anymore can anyone help me. TIA

Comment: What does the error say? Check your error log

Comment: Yes add the error pls :)

Comment: you are using post method to send data at the same type you are also using get method. use proper syntax for jquery post or get method, this shall solve you problem.

Comment: Thanks Rajesh, you're right. There's no errors in log just the 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by the help of someone.

```
 $SubCat = SubCat::find()
            ->where(['category_id' => $id])
            ->all();

if (!empty($SubCat)) {
    foreach($SubCat as $subcat) {
        echo "<option value'".$subcat->id."'>".subcat->sub_category."</option>";
    }
}
else {
    echo "<option>-</option>";
}
```

}